# if function for rowSums_Modify the code

Tags: r

I want to get summation over several columns and make a new column based on them. So I use

```
df$Sum <-rowSums(df[,grep("y", names(df))])
```

But sometimes `df` just includes one column and in this case, I will get the error. Since this function is part of my long programming procedure, I was wondering how I can make an if function in a way that If `df[,grep("y", names(df))]` includes just one column then get sum is equal to `df[,grep("y", names(df))]` otherwise if `df[,grep("y", names(df))]` have more at leat two columns get the summation over them? 
suppose:

```
require(stats); require(graphics)
attach(cars)
cars$y1<-seq(20:69)
#cars$y2<-seq(30:79)
df<-cars
df$Sum <-rowSums(df[,grep("y", names(df))])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `drop = FALSE` when subsetting:

```
df$Sum <-rowSums(df[,grep("y", names(df)), drop = FALSE])
```

This keeps `df` as a data frame even if you are selecting only one column.